# applicationShouldHandleReopen is no longer called in Lion/XCode 4.1

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I've just installed OS X Lion and XCode 4.1.

I have an app that opens the last used document automatically at startup. To do so I have implemented applicationShouldHandleReopen.

This app used to launch fine from XCode 4.0.2 on Snow Leopard.

After I compiled my app with XCode 4.1 it stopped working.

I put a break point inside applicationShouldHandleReopen, but it never breaks unless I click on the app icon on dock.

When I double click the app in Finder as opposed to running it from XCode 4.1, it works as expected; it launches the last document, meaning applicationShouldHandleReopen must have been called at startup.

Any ideas what happened? What should I do to bring back the old behavior?

Or do you think this is a bug in XCode 4.1?

Thanks

Comment: One option would be to require Lion and switch to supporting its own Resume feature instead of implementing your own.

Comment: You say “When I double click the app …, it works as expected”. Do you mean while it is already running?

Comment: >> Do you mean while it is already running? A: I meant running the app directly from Finder by double clicking on MyApp.app in the file list.


>> Switch to..Resume feature.. A: I can't do that as I still would like to support Snow Leopard customers.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Do you mean double-clicking on the app in the Finder while it is already running?

Comment: BTW I logged this problem as a bug at Apple Developer platform:
Problem ID: 9833028

Comment: It seems when you debug and stop your app from XCode 4.1 the app may not be terminated even though it might give that impression to the user. I realised that when I cold boot the system it works the first time (i.e. the app stops at BP) but it doesn't in consecutive Command+R attempts. It seems the debugged app is cached and not truly terminated. This is bizarre. I cannot support my Snow Leopard customers if they need an update from me. Lets see what Apple has to say.

Comment: Opening an app that isn't already open is not a reopen. Reopen is specifically opening the app (via Launch Services; e.g., from the Finder) while it is already open. If the app is not already running, you should not get a reopen event, cold boot or not. ❖ What leads you to believe the process is not exiting? Does it appear in ps? Does the process ID change?

Comment: Peter I would like to answer you but the answer is lengthy and requires formatted text. If you are a member of Apple Developer program you might be able to read the bug report I lodged (9833028). There is more info there and precise steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found that clicking on the "Stop" button (black square on top left) which used to truly stop the app in XCode 4.0.2, or stopping and restarting another debugging session with Command+R causes this behavior in XCode 4.1. The workaround is to use your application's own Quit command to terminate it. "Stop" from XCode is no longer working. I am glad that at least I have a workaround. The bug remains. I updated my bug report in Apple with an amendment.

Comment: Only Apple employees can read bug reports in Radar. If your bug report doesn't contain any confidential information, you may want to publish it on OpenRadar: http://openradar.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. I don't observe this behavior any more.